# SQL Group By Help Required

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table named People in the following format:

`Date | Name`.

When I count the people by Grouping By Name with

```
Select Date, Name, count(*)
From People
Group By Date, Name;
```

Will give the following

```
Date        Name        count(*)
10          Peter       25
10          John        30
10          Mark        25
11          Peter       15
11          John        10
11          Mark        5
```

But I would like the following result:

```
Date    Peter   John    Mark
10      25      30      25
11      15      10      5
```

Is this possible? This is a simple example of a more complicated database. If someone helps me in solving this problem I will use the concept to implement it in my table

Thanks!

Comment: What SQL product are you using (hint: search for pivot and whatever RDBMS you're using, and you should find the answer)?

Comment: Hi, which RDBMS do you use? If you use MS-SQL try to use the `PIVOT`- Statement.

Comment: Further to @Damian's comment - I would seatch for your RDBMS platform with search terms `pivot` and `crosstab` and you should find out if this is possible or not...

Comment: This is usually known as a Pivot (table). Depending on your RDBMS there may be non-standard functions to do this, else you'll find yourself hard-coding each `Name` in `CASE` statements. Reporting tools are better at handling this sort of output.

Comment: Duplicate of [column value in a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323117/column-value-in-a-single-row) and likely many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Date
     , count(case when Name = 'Peter' then 1 else null end)
     , count(case when Name = 'John' then 1 else null end)
     , count(case when Name = 'Mark' then 1 else null end)
From People
Group By Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

another option different from turbanoff's if, for some reason, you find yourself in a situation that you cant apply a group by:

```
Select distinct(P.Date), 
       (select count(*) from People where date=p.date and name='Peter') as Peter,
       (select count(*) from People where date=p.date and name='John') as John,
       (select count(*) from People where date=p.date and name='Mark') as Mark
From People P
```